# laravel 5.8 form::model not working, Post form is sent as Get

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, laravel-5

I have an error in one of my forms, all the others work but in particular I cannot edit in this one since it does not send the post from a form created with Form :: model (), it took me a while to realize that this was the problem, although I have defined the form as POST the data is sent as GET and it does not find the route since it is defined as POST.

This is my failed code:

```
{!! Form::model($nota, [
'method' => 'POST',
'url' => ['/admin/notas', $nota->id],
'class' => 'form-horizontal',
'files' => true]) !!}

@include('admin.notas.form', ['formMode' => 'edit'])

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

But later I realized that if I copy the html generated by this code and paste it raw, there it works!

```
<form method="POST" action="https://mydomain/admin/notas/{{$nota->id}}" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf

@include('admin.notas.form', ['formMode' => 'edit'])
</form>
```

It is worth mentioning that this form allowed to edit correctly beforehand, and that in localhost (WAMP) it works correctly, I already confirmed that my model, controller and routes are fine, but everything fails from the submit and does not reach the route defined as Post because it is sent as Get.

Note:
The problem is gone, I was about to upload the form with raw html to get out of the error and I realized that the error was corrected, I do not know if it was a server error, the strange thing is that other forms did not fail and when submitting the form laravel did not throw me any error.

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify the method, POST is the default. But look at the generated code in your browser's source, and see what the method is there. If it's POST, watch the Network tab to see if it's being redirected, such as an HTTP -> HTTPS redirect.

Comment: Sure, I tried with or without specifying the POST method, the same with PATCH and PUT with the same result that the form is sent by GET.

Comment: Check the source in the browser to see what the method is listed as once the page is rendered. If it's POST there, then watch the Network tab when you submit the form to see if there are any redirects.